# ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0'

Tags: wine, compiling, lutris

So its been a long time dream of mine to run Fireworks on Linux
I assume somehow I am running the wrong version?
`gamemode is already the newest version (1.5.1-0ubuntu3.1).`

**Running with**

- Lutris: `0.5.8.3`
- Kernel: `5.8.0-53-generic`
- Wine version: `lutris-6.10-7-86_64`
- DKVK version: `v1.7.3L-03f11ba`

Error Log

```
Running gamemoderun /home/hutber/.local/share/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-6.10-7-x86_64/bin/wine /mnt/users/Games/Games/fireworks/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Adobe Fireworks CS6/Fireworks.exe
Initial process has started with pid 251133
Start monitoring process.
gamemodeauto: 
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
wineserver: using server-side synchronization.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Monitored process exited.
Initial process has exited (return code: 13568)
All monitored processes have exited.
Exit with returncode 13568
```

Comment: Is your $LIB set to lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ?

Comment: Ahh smart and also obvious!! $LIB is not set to anything!

Comment: Ok so the $LIB is set now to the correct path. `echo $LIB
lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`  But I am confused I assume I point to my system `usr/lib` folder and not the VM's as that does not exsit.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah so you're missing the 32bit libs. Remove gamemode (`apt remove gamemode --autoremove`), and download the Debian packages:

```
https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/gamemode/download
https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/gamemode-daemon/download
https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libgamemode0/download
https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libgamemodeauto0/download
https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libgamemode0/download
https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libgamemodeauto0/download
```

then install all .deb's with this command:

`apt install -f path/to/gamemode.deb path/to/gamemode-daemon.deb` ...
This should fix your problem.

Taken from: https://github.com/FeralInteractive/gamemode/issues/254#issuecomment-643648779